# Which JS methods/libs to extract selected arrays and properties from a complex object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have an array of JSON objects such as below:

```
{

            title: 'foo',
            alias: 'bam',

            innerArr: [{
              name:'foo',
              id:'123',
              options: [{id:3,title:'boo',values:[{id:5,name:'Boo'}] }]
            }]
}
```

Is there any library or shorthand method that doesn't involve writing nested for loops that will iterate over a collection of such objects and create a new array, but only with the properties I want projected/selected. So, say I want a copy of this array, but don't want the property `title` and the nested `options[{}]` array in the target array. So this new array will have all the same data, but each member of the array will now not have those two objects. Something I can overload like so perhaps `var newarr = method({}, sourceArray, {title, options });`

Comment: Any method used would anyway iterate through array

Answer (score 0):

Just create a clone object (or you could work on initial object) and delete what you want, e.g:

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
delete newObj.title;
newObj.innerArr.forEach(function(_o, i){delete _o.options});
console.log(newObj);
```

If you have to deal with specific nested objects as `Date`, use jQuery extend to clone object.

```
var newObj = $.extend({}, oldObject);
```

> Let's say I have an array of JSON objects

For an array of object:

```
var newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
newArr.forEach(function (_o, i) {
    delete _o.title;
    _o.innerArr.forEach(function (__o, i) {
        delete __o.options
    });
});
console.log(newArr);
```

### *-jsFiddle-*

***EDIT:*** now i guess some library as [prototypejs](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/) would have some handful methods but i don't know this library.